# Can't read from CSV

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, datatable

I followed [Jim Scott's instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1050278/10572755) to read CSV into a `DataTable` with the following code:

```
private OleDbConnection CNN = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="+Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=Yes\"");
private OleDbCommand CMD;
private OleDbDataAdapter ADT;
private DataTable DT=new DataTable();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CNN.Open();
    CMD = new OleDbCommand(@"select * from [Report.csv]", CNN);
    ADT = new OleDbDataAdapter(CMD);
    ADT.Fill(DT);
}
```

I had put the `Report.csv` under the root directory, and tried following things to no avail!

1. Changed **`Data Source`** to `localhost`, `(localhost)`, `~`, `~\\`.
2. Changed `Report.csv` to `Report`.
3. Finally change **`Data Source`** to `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` to get it to connect correctly.

Problem: It can **NOT** find `Report.csv`!

> I wish this to be a webpage, so what I need is a way for the `OleDbConnection` connect to **`localhost`** and pointed to the root directory!
>
> It will be VERY nice if somebody could teach me how to do that!

Somebody please be so kind and tell me where did I do wrong and how to set it up correctly!

Much appreciated!!!

Comment: Root directory <> GetCurrentDirectory(). Put it in `c:\\` and change your code to match, and make sure it works.

Comment: Check the value returned by `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` and store it there. You seem to be just hoping you're putting the file in the correct place.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But please note that my tag includes **ASP.net**! I intended to publish this as a website, so unfortunately the **solution** is not as easy as **Put it in C:**.

Comment: Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() may give the directory where the current asp.net webpage is located

Comment: OK, let me go try it! Thanks!

Comment: see my updated answer,

Comment: Wait! Let me changed my question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, its a path issue. Can you try doing the following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CNN.Open();
    string fileName = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Report.csv";
    string sqlQuery = @"select * from [" + fileName + "]";
    CMD = new OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, CNN);
    ADT = new OleDbDataAdapter(CMD);
    ADT.Fill(DT);
}
```

**Update:**

Instead of  `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`, you can use `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~")` which will give the path of the current root.

If your website is at:

```
C:\Web\shop
```

and you are accessing webpage: http://localhost:8080/Application/users/userdetails.aspx

```
 1. Server.MapPath(".") returns C:\Web\shop\users 
 2. Server.MapPath("~") returns C:\Web\shop\
```

Comment: Possibly also a permissions issue.

Comment: Thanks! That solved it! But the encoding is WAY~ off! Let me go see if I can find anything about it! An reference link will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467300/how-can-i-get-csv-file-encoding-utf-8-in-c-net (refer to the answer with 4 upvotes)..

Comment: I solved it by adding `CharacterSet=65001` under the `Extended Properties` in connection string!